# Vim: Move left at the beginning of a line should go to above line

Tags: vim, text-editor

In usual text editors, when you move your cursor left at the beginning of a line, the cursor goes up at the end of the above line. Is it possible to get this behavior in Vim?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`:set ww+=<,>` should make the left and right movement wrap to previous/next line. `:help whichwrap` for more information.

Comment: geirha, it might be better to keep the vim default of b,s so perhaps you could suggest :set ww+=<,> or :set ww=b,s,<,>

Comment: @skyblue good point, I'll update the answer.